# Ubuntu 18.04 on UNetbootin bootable 16GB USB Flash Drive will install on PC but not on new Laptop

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, usb

I have a new, Metabox laptop with a 500GB SSD on which Windows 10 is installed and a 2TB HDD.  My 4 year old PC has a 180GB SSD running Windows 10 and a 2TB HDD for storage.  I originally intended installing Ubuntu on the laptop's HDD but now believe it may be best to install it on the SSD.  Both computers have good specs with regards to RAM, etc.

I have followed the advice of various Ubuntu website contributors and created a bootable USB Flash Drive using Rufus, then Universal USB Installer, then UNetbootin, all having the ability to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to Dual Boot with the Windows 10 O.S. installed by the laptop's manufacturer, Metabox.  I attempted to disable Secure Boot as repeatedly advised, only to find it was already disabled, obviously by the Windows 10 installer.

On every occasion, when booted from the USB Flash Drive, it has failed to run or install Ubuntu.  It crashes/freezes and I have to shut it down by holding down the power button.  I finally tried the current, UNetbootin version on my PC, expecting the same but it displayed a thorough tour of Ubuntu 18.04, no worries.  I did not try to Install it but have no doubt it would have installed had I attempted it.

Can someone please explain how I might install Ubuntu 18.04 on my new laptop, preferably to Dual Boot with Windows 10, as it seems the problem is with my laptop and not the bootable USB Flash Drive.  Thank you.

Comment: I just installed 18.04 on ASUS laptop was having similar problems, until I moved USB flash drive from USB 3 port to normal USB. Still don't know why. Maybe old flash drive. Anyway worth a try.

Comment: Thanks Bob.  The USB 3 -v- USB 2 possibility was one of the first things I tried.  Whether in USB3 Port, or USB2, same result - crash/freeze.  It's demoralizing.  I've been weeks trying to resolve this - no luck.  PS  The success on my PC was using the USB3 port.